# as3 I'm lost, how can I move different text objects?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I recently started fiddling around with as3, which look pretty good, problem is I come from as2 and I'm completely lost.

I'm tring to import text from 4 text files then move them on on top of the other:

text1 x = 100, text2 x=150 text3 x=200 etc..

Here is where I'm stuck:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myTextField_txt:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField_txt.wordWrap=true;
myTextField_txt.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;

var i:int = 0;
var ipsilon:int = 200;

for(i;i<5;i++) {
        myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("text"+i+".txt"));
}
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var testo = e.target.data;
    styleMe(testo);
}
function styleMe(testo){
    //Associamo il testo alla variabile
    myTextField_txt.text = testo;
    //Formato Carattere
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 15;
    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    myTextField_txt.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    //Formato Varie
    myTextField_txt.textColor = 0x000000;
    myTextField_txt.border = true;
    myTextField_txt.borderColor = 0x999999;
    myTextField_txt.width = 200;
    myTextField_txt.height = 20;
    myTextField_txt.background = true;
    myTextField_txt.backgroundColor = 0xFFCC00;
    //Posizione
    myTextField_txt.x = 0;
    myTextField_txt.y = -100;
    var text1 = addChild(myTextField_txt);
    tweenMe(text1);
}
function tweenMe(text1){
    Tweener.addTween(text1, {x:450,y:200, time:5});
}
```

I can't understand how do I tell actionscript to move them in different position.

Thank you very much for your patience

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uhm, there would be a hacky solution ... but you should try a clean solution, using classes ...

i am not completely sure, what you want to do, but this should do the trick:

```
package  {
    import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    public class MyText extends TextField {
        private var _tweenParams:Object;
        public function MyText(location:String, tweenParams:Object, initVars:Object = null) {

            this._tweenParams = { };
            for (var name:String in tweenParams) this._tweenParams[name] = tweenParams[name];
            for (name in initVars) this[name] = initVars[name];

            (new URLLoader(new URLRequest(location))).addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);

            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.size = 15;
            myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
            this.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;

            this.textColor = 0x000000;
            this.border = true;
            this.borderColor = 0x999999;
            this.width = 200;
            this.height = 20;
            this.background = true;
            this.backgroundColor = 0xFFCC00;            
        }
        private function onLoad(e:Event):void {
            this.text = e.target.data;
            Tweener.addTween(this, this._tweenParams);
        }
    }
}
```

and then just use it like this:

```
this.addChild(new MyText("text1.txt",{x:0,y:0, time:5},{y:-100}));
this.addChild(new MyText("text2.txt",{x:200,y:0, time:5},{y:-100}));
this.addChild(new MyText("text3.txt",{x:400,y:0, time:5},{y:-100}));
this.addChild(new MyText("text4.txt",{x:600,y:0, time:5},{y:-100}));
```

hope that helps ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Looks like it's correct. but it throws this error: 5000: The class 'Main' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.

Comment: It throws the same error even if I add: import flash.display.MovieClip';

Comment: Nevermind, I was using the MyText.as as the document class. After importing it in the main frame everything works.. Can't understand why though..